# Schema Compare tool in Visual Studio 2013 ASCII characters

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ascii, database-project, extended-ascii, schema-compare

I am comparing my project with our development database SQL Server and found a bug in the Schema Comparison tool.  I found out that any ASCII character over 127 will display as a black diamond question mark, meaning the character is not recognized.  In this example, the section symbol § is displaying as a �.  On the left hand side of the pane is the function that is included in my database project, and on the right hand side of the pane is the function on the development database server.

[Schema Comparison between Database Project and Database Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQOIn.png)

Comment: Just to let you know, the function definition in the project shows the character as a section symbol correctly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is Schema Compare showing up with these extraneous characters?  If I go an use the "Update" function from the Schema Comparison tool, it will replace the character with a black diamond question mark on the database server.  Something is definitely wrong with the Schema Compare tool.

Comment: What is the database collation set to in the project? (See project properties > Project Settings tab > Database Settings)

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.  This is the collation we use on our database server.  The character displays fine if I see it from SQL Server, or open the function/stored procedure in the project.

Comment: Is it the same one as the database and/or the table/column? I've seen those sometimes be different?  Have you tried a comparison using something like Red-Gate's Data Compare?